# Independent scrolling of StackPanels in grouped ListView

Tags: xaml, uwp, desktop-application, uwp-xaml

I currently have the following XAML for a ListView, and I want the individual panels to scroll vertically and independently of each other.

Currently, when I use the scrolling function in the stack panel, panel 1, 2 and 3 all scroll vertically together. Importantly, I do not know how many panels there will be, sometimes there will be one, and on another day there could be six.

I would like for the panels to scroll vertically and independently of the other panels.

[image]

The thing I am struggling to achieve is to make the  `<ListView.ItemsPanel>` dynamic enough to create individual stack panels, based on the groups in the data. I assume this will make the `<GroupStyle.Panel>` work independently.

I thought that the `<ItemsPanelTemplate>`  would treat them as individuals and not as a whole group.

The XAML I currently have is as follows:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeData Mode=OneWay}"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">

            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="4"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="150">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, TargetNullValue='No Data'}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>

                    <GroupStyle.Panel>                            
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>                                   
                            <StackPanel ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="4"/>                               
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>

                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4" />
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: It landed on my desk yesterday and it's a desktop application.

Comment: If I understand correctly, all of the three panels are in one listview item, and there are more of the same listview item like this one, right?

Comment: That is correct, the three panels are in the Listview. The number of panels are determined by the ItemsSource and the data that is used is an List<T> within that data. So we can have four panels and in that panel the list migh have n number of entries.

Comment: Could you please share more code snippets that could be able to reproduce the behavior you mentioned for us to test?

Comment: I will create model later and add it.